# VBA .Sort feature for List Box

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, activex

I've used this exact same VBA code before on other listboxes to add non-duplicates quite successfully. Unfortunately, this time it's giving me an error "application-defined or object-defined error." Any insights on this is greatly appreciated, I'm not sure why it's not adding the items to the list. This is an ActiveX listbox as well, that is being added on the worksheet instead of a user form. I've done this exact same code before without problems, but this time it errors out at: **rngData.Sort**

```
Private Sub lstCountry_Click()
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim strID As String
Dim rngData As Range
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim shtPivot
Set shtPivot = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot")
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
Set rngData = wsData.Range("a2").CurrentRegion


lstCountry.Clear
strID = "Select Country"
rngData.Sort key1:=strID, Header:=xlYes


For Each rngCell In rngData.Columns(1).Cells
    If rngCell.Value <> strID Then
        lstCountry.AddItem rngCell.Value
        strID = rngCell.Value
    End If
Next rngCell
```

Attached is a screenshot of the table that I'm trying to sort
[image]

Comment: this code would call itself at every `lstCountry.AddItem` statement. furthermore I can't understand that `strID = rngCell.Value` into `For Each rngCell` loop: what's your real goal?

Comment: My goal is to add the values from the screenshot I just attached to a listbox without duplicates. I've done this before successfully, just this time I'm getting an error and I'm not sure why!

Comment: which worksheet is the ActiveX listbox you want to process in? how do you fill it the first time?

Comment: @user3598756 The activeX Lisbox is on shtPivot, and the data is from another worksheet wsData. I wrote exactly the same code on another workbook for the same function (diff string data), and it worked with no problems. That's why I'm wondering why this time it gets stuck at rngData.Sort

Comment: how do you fill listbox the first time?

Comment: with that exact same code.

Comment: how do you trigger a `Click` event of an empty listbox?

Comment: I just figured it out. I recopied the table that I'm pulling info from into another sheet, and my code worked. This is odd that it won't work on the exact same table on another worksheet. I don't get it, but I'll go with my newly copied table instead. I appreciate the help.:-)

Comment: It wouldn't be empty if the code worked in the first place. But now that I fixed it, the list is properly populated, so the event works as intended with the rest of my code.

Comment: but there must have been a beginning, when the listbox was empty. I wonder how could your code run then?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I recopied the table that I'm pulling info from into another sheet, and my code worked. This is odd that it won't work on the exact same table on another worksheet. I don't get it, but I'll go with my newly copied table instead. I appreciate the help.:-)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a good example how to use the sort option:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx

In your case, most probably you do not have "Select Country" written on the top of your range. Your top range is row 2. Can you give a screenshot?

Comment: I just attached a screenshot. Thank you

Comment: can you change strID to the following `strID = wsData.Range("a2")`

Comment: Nothing gets added if I do that @vityata